# What is best practice for global error/exception handling in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I've seen two methods of implementing global error handling in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. One method is via the `Application_Error` method in `Global.asax.cs`.

For example ([Error Handling in global.asax](http://forums.asp.net/t/1505777.aspx)):

```
public class SomeWebApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication {

  // ... other methods ...

  protected void Application_Error() {
    // ... application error handling code ...
  }
}
```

The other method is via a `[HandleError]` action filter attribute registered in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method, again in `Global.asax.cs`.

Which is the better way to approach this? Are there any significant disadvantages to either approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[HandleError]` is the way to go since it keeps everything simple and responsibility is clear. This [action filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is a specific [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) feature and therefore is the official way of handling errors. It's also quite easy to override the filter to add custom functionality.

`Application_Error` is the old way to do it and doesn't really belong in MVC.

The `[HandleError]` attribute works fine as long as you remember to tag your controllers (or the base controller) with it.

**Update**:

Created a blog entry: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: an error controller and using the default `<customErrors>` section in web.config.

Comment: @PsychoDad: `customErrors` in web.config and an error controller.

Comment: customErrors redirecting which is not quite well, how to just change view and leave 404 status code?

Comment: @dan: customErrors in web.config (defaultRedirect) handles non-404 exceptions outside of the MVC pipeline.

What about AJAX errors? Selective Result returned based on request type?

Comment: Your blog link gives a connection timeout