# When to load database drive configuration settings in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

At application start our application connects to the database and fetches a language translation table and caches it into memory. The code that does this is placed in Application_Start in Global.ascx

The problem with this approach is that if the database is not available, there will be a completely unhandled exception. Because the code is set at Application_Start, `Request` and `Response` are not available.

I was wondering if there's a general lightweight approach to this.

My plan is to implement a singleton to store the state of the connection attempt, and then check that on the default routed page. It's a solution, but I feel there's something missing. Are there any other approaches to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem with this approach is that if the database is not
>   available, there will be a completely unhandled exception.

Well handle it then. You could implement some retry policy in your code so that if the result is not cached in memory it will fetch it from the database once again.

Comment: I was hoping there existed a better solution. The more I think about it, our application would benefit to move all the initialization stuff into a place where exceptions can be caught and outcome can be displayed to the user. `Application_Start` is just not the place for such initialization.

Answer (score 2):

The excellent article about the error handling can be find at http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/#.UZsZ6LVTAus
. And [jgauffin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70386/jgauffin) also had a discussion's thread at [What is best practice for global error/exception handling in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511752/what-is-best-practice-for-global-error-exception-handling-in-asp-net-mvc)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. We have a pretty good approach right now, both in BLL/DAL (log4net) and web app (elmah). My problem was regarding doing initialization at `Application_Start` where you don't have the luxuries of proper error handling.